# Combining duplicate rows and concatenating the unique field in a certain format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have a question that might be simple to answer, I just haven't found what I'm looking for online. Please excuse my ignorance I mostly work in access.

I have a few hundred thousand listings of products, they're categorized by **Application**, **Make**, **Model**, **year** and **part #**. Now what I want to accomplish is that if Application, make, model and part # hold the same values, they get combined into the same row, and the Years get put into the format `YYYY-YYYY` (ex. 2010-2013).

Is there any way to accomplish this with vba or a formula? ? I can clarify any confusions if I'm not making myself clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a function on the Data tab to remove duplicates - would that help?

Comment: It is most definitely doable in [tag:VBA].  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @rheitzman I did find it, thank you. The issue is combining these fields together and having it's years (which are different) concatenate into a specific format.

Comment: @Degustaf I'm not proficient in VBA, so what I've been doing is assigning keys and creating additional columns creating max and min, but it's too much workaround for over 300k products. I mostly get stuck around inputting the years for the duplicate products, they're all the same except for year, I would like them to be one record and combine the year for example 2010-2013.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable can do nearly all of this work for you since it will automatically removed duplicates.  Only step missing would be the hyphenated "YYYY - YYYY" format.

Place a PivotTable over all of your data and then put **Application, Make, Model, Part #** in the "Row Lables" section.  Secondly, pull the **Year** field into the "Values" section two separate times.  With the first of these two, change the calculation to "Min of Year" and change the other calculation to "Max of Year".

After clicking on the PivotTable, you will see a "Design" tab in the ribbon.  Adjust the following settings in this tab:

1. Subtotals > Do Not Show Subtotals
2. Grand Totals > Off for Rows and Columns
3. Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form
4. Report Layout > Repeat All Item Lables

Using these settings on the PivotTable with this raw sample data:

```
App #   Make #  Model #     Year    Part #
App 1   Make 1  Model 1     2010    Part 1
App 1   Make 1  Model 1     2011    Part 1
App 1   Make 1  Model 1     2012    Part 1
App 2   Make 1  Model 1     2010    Part 1
App 2   Make 1  Model 1     2011    Part 2
App 2   Make 2  Model 1     2012    Part 1
App 2   Make 3  Model 1     2013    Part 1
```

Will output a PivotTable that shows:

```
App #   Make #  Model # Part #      Min of Year    Max of Year
App 1   Make 1  Model 1 Part 1      2010           2012
App 2   Make 1  Model 1 Part 1      2010           2010
App 2   Make 1  Model 1 Part 2      2011           2011
App 2   Make 2  Model 1 Part 1      2012           2012
App 2   Make 3  Model 1 Part 1      2013           2013
```

Comment: thank you for the response, ok I tried this, and everything seems to go well except for min and max year, I get 0 on both columns, I followed the same settings you did for the pivot table. I wonder what I could be missing?

Comment: when I add it initially it adds as "count of year", changing it to min it changes its values to 0, same thing with max

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure Jeff.  I tried to duplicate this error through some different scenarios and couldn't get the data to return a value of 0.  Can you confirm all of the Year data is formatted to Number or Date value?  Does the pivot also return 0 for other types of calculations such as "Sum of Year"?

Comment: hm I thought it might have been the value type, I have it formatted as number, I just changed it to Sum of Year and it turns to 0, in count it shows certain values (I'm guessing the amount of years). It's weird that min or max automatically gives me a 0

Comment: Sounds like all of the Year data is formatted to Text value, causing the calculations to not work.